# Python httpx post json data with dropdown menu

Tags: python, post, request, httpx

I'm trying to make a post request to a site with json dropdown data.

This is the Payload:

```
{token: "something",…}
  events: [{type: "impression_user_verify_phone",…}]
    0: {type: "impression_user_verify_phone",…}
    properties: {client_track_timestamp: 1652961971362, impression_type: "modal", location: 
      "impression_friends",…}
       accessibility_features: 524416
       accessibility_support_enabled: false
       client_performance_memory: 0
       client_send_timestamp: 1652961971397
       client_track_timestamp: 1652961971362
       client_uuid: "HgBCFQ7xjA3RpVW54Kw13IABAAAKAAAA"
       impression_type: "modal"
       location: "impression_friends"
       location_page: "impression_friends"
       location_section: "impression_user_verify_phone"
       rendered_locale: "tr"
       type: "impression_user_verify_phone"
token: "something"
```

[For visual reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Ecx.jpg)

How can I pass this data to a post request with the httpx module?

Comment: that's not valid json (keys must be quoted strings), looks like javascript

Comment: to send a json payload via httpx, see docs https://www.python-httpx.org/quickstart/#sending-json-encoded-data